# Calling convention incorrect despite setting?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to compile some driver code that was last compiled in VC++ 6.0 with Visual Studio 2015.

The linker keeps giving me warning LNK4086 stating:

> entrypoint '_DriverEntry@8' is not __stdcall with 12 bytes of arguments; image may not run

The method should be using the **__stdcall** convention as the project has the **/Gz** option set. I even tried to manually add the option to get it to be happy, but the linker still complains:

```
_Use_decl_annotations_
NTSTATUS
__stdcall
DriverEntry(
    PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    )
```

This warning prevents me from finishing the compile because it tells me:

> warning treated as error; no output file generated

Here are my linker options (I removed the filename for privacy purposes):

> /OUT:"[FILENAME REMOVED].sys" /MANIFEST:NO /PROFILE /NXCOMPAT /Driver /PDB:"[FILENAME REMOVED].pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "wdm.lib" "usbd.lib" /RELEASE /IMPLIB:"[FILENAME REMOVED].lib" /VERSION:"4.0" /DLL /BASE:"0x10000" /MACHINE:X86 /ENTRY:"DriverEntry" /WX /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"[FILENAME REMOVED].pgd" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /MERGE:".rdata=.text" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"\lib\i386\checked" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\km\x86\" /NODEFAULTLIB /SECTION:"INIT,d"

Comment: The error is with the *"12 bytes of arguments"*. It's taking 8 only.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the details of calling conventions and had assumed the disconnect in the byte count was related to those differences. I can't add arguments or anything as I have to follow the convention for implementing [DriverEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544113(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What are the linker options you are using?

Comment: @MatteoItalia There are several pages of linker options, some of which are default, some of which were inherited from the original VC++6 project. Do you want me to just post screenshots of all of them or do you have something specific you are looking for?

Comment: Look at the 'Command Line' page to see all the options in one place, as text that you can copy. I don't quite understand how the `DriverEntry` function is expected to be 12 bytes when it takes two pointers; surely it would either be only 8 or 16 depending on the platform?

Comment: I have added the linker options to the question body.

Comment: Not saying that's the problem, but shouldn't there be a `/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE` among those linker options?

Comment: @Cameron The linker likely mistakes the driver for a regular `/DLL` and expects the entry point to have the same signature as [_DllMain@12](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988ye33t.aspx).

Comment: @dxiv That seems like a the most likely scenario.